# how to upload image through drupal7 service

Tags: drupal-7

In my project I am using Drupal service module i.e services 7.x-3.7. I am having problem in uploading particular image in specific folder on server. I am getting the image in byte format from IOS. I need to get that image data i.e byte data and want to store on server in image format.

Can I get some code example explaining this. It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks In Advance
Praful

Comment: Please be more specific. Exactly what are you trying to do, what are the results? These information are not enough to understand you problem...

Comment: Just I want to create a web service in Drupal 7 by using service module. This service will call from IOS application (IPhone). In that user can set his profile picture. IOS developer will send me the image by converting into byte. What I need to do is, to store that particular image on my server.so,next time I'll send the url of that particular image to IOS and he can download this and show on IOS side.